# how to dispatch same action with different params in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I would like to know how to dispatch action with different params in react redux.

In format.js,  `queryData` with different param is called by  `callFetch` method.
After props dispatch, in the render method,  will receive data in props `memberData`,

I receive the response `memberData`with status `Inactive` but
How to display for both the `Active` and `Inactive`,

```
// format.js

componentDidMount(){
 this.callFetch();
}

callFetch(){
    this.props.dispatch(queryData(this.createFetchUrl("Active")));
    this.props.dispatch(queryData(this.createFetchUrl("Inactive")));
}

createFetchUrl(status) {
   const body ={
     position: "civil",
     status: status 
   }
  return body;
}

render(){
  const { memberData } = this.props.data
  return(
     <div>
     Active 
     <p>{memberData}</p>
     Inactive
     <p>{memberData}</p>
    </div>
  )
}


//actions.js
export const queryDeviceByMember = payload =>
  queryApi({
    request: CONSTANTS.DATA,
    url: `api/details`,
    encode: false,
    success: CONSTANTS.DATA_SUCCESS,
    failure: CONSTANTS.DATA_FAILURE,
    ...payload
  });

//reducer.js

    case CONSTANTS.DATA_SUCCESS:
    case CONSTANTS.DATA_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        memberData: data,
        apiPending: false,
        errormsg: errormsg,
        servererror: servererror || ""
      };
```

am receiving the same response for both `active` and `inactive` states, since it overrides, without overriding how to do

```
[{
   id: "20",
   name: "xxx",
   device: "ios"
 },
 {
   id: "10",
   name: "yyy",
   device: "ios"
 }]
```

Comment: can you please provide a sample response and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the data in `memberData`, consider following these steps:

1. Split your reducers for `active` and `inactive` cases
2. Use a selector to select the data from your state, i.e:

```
export const getActiveMembers = state => state.activeMembers;
export const getInactiveMembers= state => state.inactiveMembers;
```

3. Import the selectors from step 2 into your components, and use `mapStateToProps(state)` to get the data from your state:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        activeMembers: getActiveMembers(state),
        subscription: getInactiveMembers(state)
    };
}
```

4. Use the data in render:

```
render(){
 const { memberData } = this.props.data
 return(
    <div>
    Active 
    <p>{memberData}</p>
    Inactive
    <p>{memberData}</p>
   </div>
 )
}
```

5. Good Luck

**P.S: I would use one API call to get all the `members` and then classify them to `inactive` & `active` in my state using the reducer.**

Comment: thanks for reply, is it possible to append the response data in reducer in each call for `active` `inactive` status